# Mapping images and their labels

Tags: python, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I have **images** in a folder(train) and csv file(train.csv) containing **image names** and **labels**.
how to map images in one folder and labels in another csv file
how can i create a data frame with image data and labels.

*multiclass classification*

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd

class MyTrainingData(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, file, labels, batchSize):
        self.file = file
        self.label = labels
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.n_bathces = int(len(self.file) / self.batchSize)



    def on_epoch_end(self):  # it is called after every epoch
        self.file, self.label = shuffle(self.file, self.label)
        for i in range(50):
            print(self.file[i], self.label[i], 'file-label')


    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_bathces
    

    # called after every batch to get new batch or new 32 images and labels
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # this method calls by fit method with idx ranging from 0 to len(training_exmaples) / batch_size =
        batchX = self.file[idx*self.batchSize: (idx+1)*self.batchSize]
        batchY = self.label[idx*self.batchSize: (idx+1)*self.batchSize]
        imgFiles = [image.load_img(name, target_size=(224, 224, 3)) for name in batchX]   #loading 32 images
        imgFiles = [image.img_to_array(img) for img in imgFiles]   #preprocessing
        imgFiles = [img / 255 for img in imgFiles]        batchY = to_categorical(batchY, 4)    # 4 represent number of classes (4 in that case)
        return np.array(imgFiles), np.array(batchY)


def getfilePath(filenames):
    path = './train/'  # or any other path according to directory structure
    filePaths = []
    for name in filenames:
        filePaths.append(path + name)   # './train/' + 'img1.jpg' = './train/img1.jpg

    return filePaths

df = pd.read_csv()
img_names = df['img_names']
labels = df['labels']
img_names = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', -----]
img_names = getfilePath(img_names)
img_names = ['./train/img1.jpg', './train/img2.jpg', -----]
label = [3, 1, 2, 0, ----]

batch_size = 32 

data = MyTrainingData(fileNames, labels, batchSize

model = defineModel()
sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.0001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

The above code does much more than mapping. In case of large dataset(to big to fit in RAM). this techniwue will help you to load, preprocess and generate input data dynamically. Hope you find it usefull. Give feedback so that i can further improve it.